# Docker private registry push error "Get https://172.17.3.50:443/v2/: dial tcp 172.17.3.50:443: connect: no route to host"

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-desktop

I am trying to push a docker image to a private docker repository from ubuntu machine on local network.

When I go to the url https://172.17.3.50:443/v2/, everything looks fine.
When I push an image to a private registry, I receive an error "Get https://172.17.3.50:443/v2/: dial tcp 172.17.3.50:443: connect: no route to host"

Answer (score 0):

Spin up a different container `docker run -ti ubuntu` and test if you can reach your registry with `curl https://172.17.3.50:443/v2/`