# How do I resolve this Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp 52.1.184.176:443: connect: no route to host

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-api

I was getting started with dockers, following the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#set-up-the-repository) and stumbled onto this Error:

`$ docker run hello-world`
with the response:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon:
Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp 52.1.184.176:443: connect: no route to host.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I have tried rebooting the server and restarting daemon and docker service with

`$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

`$ sudo systemctl restart docker`

but it had no effect on the Error.

There is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75543429/docker-private-registry-push-error-get-https-172-17-3-50443-v2-dial-tcp-17) to this one. But spinning up different containers gave me the same Error and prompting `$ curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/` just threw the same kind of error `(7) Failed to connect: no route to host.`

Update: I now have tried adding more nameservers to `/etc/resolv.conf` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47580528/error-response-from-daemon-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-dial-tcp-look?rq=2) post with a new Error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http:
request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Why am I getting this Error? Can you please tell me how I can resolve this issue?